# Does sqlalchemy work on msys2 without pyodbc?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, msys2

I'm trying to use sqlalchemy on windows10 in msys2 environment. However pyodbc which seems to be one of the sqlalchemy requirements does not seem to exist on https://packages.msys2.org/package/ where all other msys2 packages are available to download and install via pacman. I'm confused why sqlalchemy is even packaged and offered on that site if pyodbc is not available on msys2? What am I missing? By the way, using standard python on windows (not via msys2) does provide both sqlalchemy and pyodbc to install via pip and everything works as expected using those packages.

Comment: SQLAlchemy only requires pyodbc when using the `mssql+pyodbc://` dialect.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunatelly that is exactly what I'm using.

Comment: Perhaps you might try `mssql+pymssql://`

Comment: Thanks. I just tried that and similar to pyodbc it works fine with regular python on windows 10 (when I used pip to install pymssql it found it and installed no problem). But again I can't find pymssql package prepared for msys2 (search on that same site I mentioned earlier fails for this package as well - and my understanding is you must use pacman vs pip to install any of these python modules for msys2 environment).

Comment: The packages site you linked does include [python-pip](https://packages.msys2.org/base/python-pip) so maybe you can install that and then use pip to install pyodbc or pymssql.